# How can I make a large python data structure more efficient to unpickle?

Tags: python, performance, serialization, pickle

I have a list of ~1.7 million "token" objects, along with a list of ~130,000 "structure" objects which reference the token objects and group them into, well, structures. It's an ~800MB memory footprint, on a good day.

I'm using `__slots__` to keep my memory footprint down, so my `__getstate__` returns a tuple of serializable values, which `__setstate__` bungs back into place. I'm also not pickling all the instance data, just 5 items for tokens, 7-9 items for structures, all strings or integers.

Of course, I'm using cPickle, and HIGHEST_PROTOCOL, which happens to be 2 (python 2.6). The resulting pickle file is ~120MB.

On my development machine, it takes ~2 minutes to unpickle the pickle. I'd like to make this faster. What methods might be available to me, beyond faster hardware and what I'm already doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pickle is not the best method for storing large amounts of similar data. It can be slow for large data sets, and more importantly, it is very fragile: changing around your source can easily break all existing datasets. (I would recommend reading what pickle at its heart actually is: a bunch of bytecode expressions. It will frighten you into considering other means of data storage/retrieval.)

You should look into using [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/), which uses HDF5 (cross-platform and everything) to store arbitrarily large amounts of data. You don't even have to load everything off of a file into memory at once; you can access it piecewise. The structure you're describing sounds like it would fit very well into a "table" object, which has a set field structure (comprised of fixed-length strings, integers, small Numpy arrays, etc.) and can hold large amounts very efficiently. For storing metadata, I'd recommend using the `._v_attrs` attribute of your tables.

Comment: Bless you. You're completely correct about the fragility issue. In development, I've had to blow away the pickle and regenerate it from the original XML (which takes ~6 minutes using `lxml`). I figured the answer might be of this general shape. I haven't run across PyTables before, and it looks to fit the bill. Thank you.

Comment: @David: Thanks! I actually implemented a primitive serialization/deserialization of a class hierarchy using PyTables and class methods, so it's definitely possible. If you're interested in the details, I can write them up.